# Visual Studio 2015 Hangs on import of large folder structure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower

I am trying to load the material-design-icon bower package into the wwwroot folder in my .net core web app.  Simply copying the material-design-icon folder into the lib directory of wwwroot will cause visual studio 2015 to hang.

What exactly is visual studio doing with this folder structure?  Is it caching the folder structure somewhere?  Are there any measures I can take to speed up whatever visual studio is doing with this folder?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things to try to improve visual studio performance, but eventually had to work around the limitation.  Tried a few IO related items such as disabling antivirus.  I also tried disabling source control in visual studio and various hide folder workarounds.  I eventually opted for removing the material icons folder from the solution completely and having it added back during the publish process.  I also had to do some "tree shaking" such that only icons that I actually used were published.  I did this by scanning all cs and cshtml files for icon usage and then only copying those files over.  Here's the script in case it helps anyone else:

```
function Publish-MaterialIcons{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path
)
process{
    $mdPath = "D:\media\material-design-icons"
    $publishPath = $(Join-Path $path "wwwroot\lib\material-design-icons")
    if (!(Test-Path $publishPath))
    {
        robocopy $mdPath $publishPath /e /xf *.* | Out-Null
    }

    "Adding $publishPath"
    $includeFonts = ls -Recurse -Include "*.cs", "*.cshtml" |% {cat $_} |? {$_ -match "([\w_]+)\</i\>"} |% {$matches[1]} | select -Unique |% {"*$_*.png","*$_*.svg"}
    $mdPathR = $mdPath -replace "\\", "\\" 
    $publishPathR = $publishPath -replace "\\", "\\"
    $(ls $mdPath -Recurse -include $includeFonts) + $(ls $mdPath -Recurse -Exclude "*.png", "*.svg")  |% {
        $newPath = join-path $($(Split-Path $_.FullName) -replace $mdPathR, $publishPathR) $_.Name
        cp $_.FullName  $newPath -Force
    }
}
}
```